# Restoring device settings from "Cupcake" malware app

Tags: settings, restore, malware

I launched the Cupcake malware application from `https://github.com/dmitrijkotov634/Cupcake` that changed my settings, not only the visual part, but also the more systemic one. I restarted the phone and couldn't enter the password because the font was large and couldn't fit on the screen, the keyboard wouldn't open.

Next, I set myself a TWRP custom and deleted the file responsible for the password from there. I logged in to the desktop without a password, changed the font to S in the settings, but then, unfortunately, the applications did not start at all, it wrote "Before opening applications, wait for the phone to complete a full reboot." I also want to note other points - many functions do not work in the settings, for example, the battery section does not open and others go deeper, I turned on ADB in the developer section, but the "USB installation" item does not turn on, activation for the developer crashes.

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Click on any application and it displays this message | The settings menu "About the application" has been changed | The settings menu "About the application" has been changed 2 |

The application could not interfere directly with the phone's root system, because I installed it and just launched it, I did not provide any root access. I believe that it somehow interacted with the existing system config available for user modification. But this is just my current opinion, I do not know how it could have happened any other way.

Can you please help me get my phone back to working condition, and return the standard values? What are the hidden system settings that can be changed by the user?

Comment: What Android version is running on your phone and is user data partition encrypted? BTW: When making screenshots please use the Android built-in screen-shot function instead of making blurred and truncated photos of the screen.

Comment: Android version 12, absolutely no apps open on the phone, no screenshots are taken. Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 pro MIUI Global 13.0.15 SKFMIXM. When I logged into data/data via TWRP, there were symbols instead of names. It's probably encrypted.

Comment: If the file-system only shows random file-names the data is encrypted via File Based Encryption (FBE). Not sure if it is possible to recover the data as you have deleted the one file.

Comment: https://github.com/dmitrijkotov634/Capcake here is the application that I launched. Can you please look at its source code? It did not completely change the root, everything should be fixed, but I do not know how

Comment: Everything interesting is in [`MainService.kt`](https://github.com/dmitrijkotov634/Cupcake/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/wavecat/cupcake/MainService.kt).

Comment: When I couldn't enter the password and had to delete the password files via twrp, maybe I just bypassed the password entry window and the system couldn't boot completely. As far as I remember, I deleted 1-2 locksettings files in data/system.db and maybe locksettings.wal, but I tried changing the password in the phone and resetting it, and then rebooting, but nevertheless the system does not start completely. An interesting point is that in TWRP, when I enter the password, they tell me that it is incorrect I set the old password from the settings, but I couldn't open the application further